# Wordpress - add item to 2 menus instead of main menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

Sorry, I didn't know how to word the title better.

I have a theme with 3 menus, a header, a subheader and a footer. I wanted to add a link that would change depending on whether the user is logged in or not. I found this code:

```
function ca_wp_nav_menu_items($items, $args) {

// Make sure this is the Primary Menu.
if ($args->theme_location == 'header') {
// CSS class to use for <li> item.
$class = 'menu-item';

if (is_user_logged_in()) {
$extra = '
<li id="menu-item-logged-in-user" class="'.$class.'">
<a href="/k/ca/mi-perfil/">
'.__('Mi Perfil').'
</a>
</li>
';
} else {
$extra = '
<li id="menu-item-logged-out-user" class="'.$class.'">
<a href="/k/ca/login/">
'.__('Ingreso').'
</a>
</li>
';
}

// Add extra link to existing menu.
$items = $items . $extra;
}
// Return menu items.
return $items;
}

// Hook into wp_nav_menu_items.
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'ca_wp_nav_menu_items', 10, 2 );
```

This works perfectly, but I'd like to modify it so the same function works for the footer menu. What has to be modified for it to work? I guess an easy way would be to copy the function and change header to footer, but I'd like to keep it simpler by just having one function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($args->theme_location == 'header' || $args->theme_location == 'footer') {
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I knew it was something simple.